# Display data from API call inside another API call

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get data from Youtube API. I'm using 2 requests, one for a list of videos, and one for details of each video.

My first request works, I display 4 videos with the thumbnail, title etc...
To get more info for each video, I tried a foreach loop inside my first API call :

This is my **service.ts**

```
    export class YoutubeDataService {

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      getList() {
         return this.http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCiRDO4sVx9dsyMm9F7eWMvw&order=date&maxResults=4&type=video&key={MY_KEY}')
      }

      getViews(id) {
         return this.http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=' + id + '&key={MY_KEY}');
      }
   }
```

This is my **component.ts**

```
    export class VideosComponent implements OnInit {

      videos: Object;
      items = [];
      views: Object;

      constructor(private youtube: YoutubeDataService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
         this.youtube.getList().subscribe(data => {
            this.videos = data.items;
            console.log(this.videos);
            this.videos.forEach(element => {
               this.youtube.getViews(element.id.videoId).subscribe(data2 => {
                  this.views = data2.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
                  console.log(this.views);
               });
            });
         });
      }

    }
```

And my **component.html**

```
    <div class="video col-xl-5" *ngFor="let video of videos.items">
       <a class="row" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={{video.id.videoId}}">
          <img [src]="video.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url">
          <div class="col"> 
             <h3 class="titre">{{ video.snippet.title }}</h3>
             // Here I'd like to display infos I can only get from the second API call
             <p class="description">{{ video.snippet.description }}</p>
          </div> 
       </a>
    </div>
```

Here, the code displays the title, the thumbnail, and the description as expected, and my `console.log(this.views);` shows the views of each video, but I can't find how to manage with it.

**UPDATE**

I understood I just needed to push the data into an array and display it with an index in my html : 
**component.ts**

```
    this.youtube.getList().subscribe(data => {
       this.videos = data.items;
       this.videos.forEach(element => {
          this.youtube.getViews(element.id.videoId).subscribe(data2 => {
             this.array.push(data2.items[0].statistics.viewCount);
          });
       });
    });
```

But I encounter a new issue: the viewcount isn't order by video. Each time I refresh the page, it displays the 4 viewcounts in a different order. Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

You are already running your first HTTP call "getList"... you are using forEach to iterate over the results and get the view counts... This is all good.

When you call the 2nd HTTP call "getViews(id)", make sure to store the results with the reference of the VideoId; This way you can simply use *ngIf to display the results when they are ready...

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let video of videos">
  <p> ID# {{video.videoId}}: {{video.title}} "{{video.description}}"</p>
  <div *ngFor="let viewership of views">
    <span *ngIf="viewership.videoId == video.videoId"> number of views: {{viewership.viewCount}} </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**relevant TS:**

```
this.videos.forEach(element =>{
  this.views.push({ "videoId":element.videoId, "viewCount": this.getViews(element.videoId) });
});
```

For working demo, take a [look here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udmlek) - Happy Learning !!

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I took inspiration from your code, but I got a new problem now with the order in the forEach. Could you please look at my updated post ?
Thank you

Comment: The Sequence of calling the 2nd function is not an issue - sequence comes into the picture at the time of displaying the viewCount; look the my HTML, where the viewCount array is being displayed inside the views array and only prints a number when the videoId is the same

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well what you mean, is that you want to get response from the first request and pipe it to the second response......if thats what you mean then you can use [request](https://github.com/request/request) easily for this ...for example

```
fetchRequest(){

  request(`FIRST_URL`,function (error, response, body){

  //error logging
  console.log('first request error:', error);

  var firstRes = JSON.parse(body)

     request(`SECOND_URL_WITH_FIRST_RES__${firstRes}`,function (error, response, body){

     //error logging
     console.log('Second request error:', error);

     var secondRes= JSON.parse(body)

     return secondRes
     }
  }

}
```